# My first ever app in production state - strange (to me) warning (MongoDB - Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mongodb

I finally got my first ever project into production.

I've got a VPS with OpenVZ6 (RHEL6, 2.6.32, Ubuntu 16.04).

I'm trying to use the MongoDB guide for production. I've got past all the warnings and I prepared it for production, yet I still get one strange (to me) warning.

```
2019-01-09T07:44:21.072-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2019-01-09T07:44:21.072-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2019-01-09T07:44:21.072-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1536M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
```

I tried to check that link and I saw this:

```
With the WiredTiger storage engine, using XFS is strongly recommended for data 
bearing nodes to avoid performance issues that may occur when using EXT4 with WiredTiger.
```

Now I don't know what I have to do. What is this XFS? Do I have to install anything, change some MongoDB file?

Basically, my question is: what does that mean and what can I do to stop getting that warning?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done some reading on the subject? For example the first Google result I found: https://scalegrid.io/blog/xfs-vs-ext4-comparing-mongodb-performance-on-aws-ec2/ -- you may want to think about changing the file system for that host.

Comment: I really did and I didn't really got what it's all about. I kind of got it, that's why I specified the kernel, linux version and everything si you could help me if I can do this. (for example, I was told I can't change the kernel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is about the [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system); it tells you that your current file system (ext4) may not perform as well as another (XFS) for the typical use case of MongoDB, which is reading and storing a lot of small data:

> When running MongoDB in production on Linux, you should use [...] the XFS or EXT4 filesystem. If possible, use XFS as it generally performs better with MongoDB.

There are a few performance comparisons out there, like [this one](https://scalegrid.io/blog/xfs-vs-ext4-comparing-mongodb-performance-on-aws-ec2/).

Whether you should choose one over the other depends on your hardware performance and performance requirements. You should ideally test the system under load and see which one performs better.

You may also decide to ignore the warning and just move on, if you think that performance is good enough.

I should add: if you are manging a production server, but are currently having difficulties understanding what the warning means, I'd recommend being very careful and double-checking with system administrators or DevOps experts. You can screw up a lot if you're not properly managing a production system, from slow performance to critical security issues.

Make sure you read the [MongoDB security checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/).

Comment: Got it. As I understand I have to change my whole VPS' file system to XFS. (am I right?). If yes, would that be okay or not?

Comment: That would be the solution, but I am not sure if a VPS would actually make that possible. Depends on the provider. In fact I'd say you should be fine leaving it as is.